# Can index in a radix be $1$?

Tags: number-theory, radicals

I am stuck at a very basic question

I had a true/false question where the statement was

"if $n$ is a natural number and $x$ a prime number $$\sqrt[n]{x}$$ is always irrational "

I was of the impression that the answer would be yes, but what if $n = 1$.
So basically my question is can $n$ take value as one ? 
And if yes what would be result in that case ?

Comment: $\sqrt[n] x\in \mathbb Z$, if and only if $n=1$ (given that $x$ is prime).

Comment: ^ Better would be $\sqrt[n]x \in \mathbb Q$ if and only if $n = 1$

Comment: I was confused because I had never see $$\sqrt[1]{x}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

> if $n$ is a natural number and $x$ a prime number, $\sqrt[n] x$ is always irrational

Is actually false since if $n=1$ then
$$\sqrt[1] x=x^{1/1}=x$$

Of course if the statement was

> if $n$ is a natural number larger than $1$ and $x$ a prime number, $\sqrt[n] x$ is always irrational

Then it would be true

---

In general

$$\sqrt[n] x=x^{1/n}$$

This means that $n$ can never be $0$ because that would result in division by zero.
There are also some other cases where the exponent is undefined (unless you're working with [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number))

When $x$ is positive, $x^n$ is always defined.

When $x$ is zero, $x^n$ is defined to be $0$ unless $n\le0$

When $x$ is negative, $x^n$ is only defined if $n$ is an integer or $n$ is fraction with an odd denominator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I was looking for values that n can take . Can an index of the radix take value 1 or negative or fractions ? I am interested in domain of index.

Comment: @user2235487 $n$ can take any value except for $0$

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could point to some resource citing that

Comment: @user2235487 By definition, $\sqrt[n] x=x^{1/n}$ so $n$ can be any value except for $0$ since that would result in division by zero. Beside that there's some cases where it cant be fractions with even denominator like $(-5)^{1/2}=\sqrt{-5}$ since that is undefined (unless you like complex numbers)

Answer (score 0):

The radical is only a short-cut notation for fractional powers. Commonly, you write $\sqrt[n]{x}$ to talk about $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Do you know what are fractional powers? Take a look at [Wiki Page about Powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents).